# How to use pow() function in the printf() statement itself?

Tags: c, pow

I am trying to use pow() function in my code to print 3 raised to the power of 2.

I used pow function in the printf() statement itself like this.

```
printf("%d",pow(3,2));
```

Output:

```
0
```

However When I tried to first assign it to a variable and then print it, It functioned perfectly.

```
int c;
c=pow(3,2);
printf("%d",c);
```

Output:

```
9
```

I have also tried to use a dummy function returning integer in the printf() statement directly and that too worked fine.

If so, what is the problem in first statement?

Comment: What compiler (and compilation options) are you using? GCC will warn for this.

Comment: `pow` is a floating-point function (arguments and return values are `double`).  Since `printf` has variable arguments, it will not cast them for you, so you need to explicitly cast the result of `pow` to `int`.  But keep in mind that using floating point for integer exponentiation is very likely to result in floating point roundoff errors, so don't be surprised if you end up with, for instance, 8 rather than 9.  Basically you shouldn't use `pow` if you want an integer result.

Comment: @melpomene I am using TDM-GCC in Dev C++ IDE. It has not given me any warnings during compilation

Comment: @Alagusankar What compilation options did you use?

Comment: @melpomene I see only TDM-GCC 4.9.2 in the compilation options

Comment: @Alagusankar What do you mean by "in the compilation options"? Do you have a screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the format specifier.  `pow` returns a `double`, whereas `%d` specifies an `int`.

Given the number of architectures out there and how very clear the demarcation between 'integral' and 'floating point' is on most platforms, in general, you cannot treat the result of a function returning `double` as an `int` in a format string and expect the correct output.

The reason it works when you assign the result of `pow` to `c` (which I assume is an `int` since it works with `%d`) is because in that case your compiler knows to implicitly cast the result, but doesn't when the only indication of the type of a variable is in a format string.

Solution: either change `%d` to `%f` or explicitly cast the result of `pow` to `int`.

Comment: To keep the behavior of the existing code, `printf("%d", (int)pow(3, 2));`.

Comment: Thanks for the typecasting suggestion

Comment: @Alagusankar If you have found that an answer has solved your problem, you may mark it as accepted by clicking the check box icon beneath the voting arrows.

Comment: Done it. Thanks for the answer